# how do i create a new windows service with chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, recipe

So chef doesn't have any builtin support for creating *new* services. I create a new windows service in one of my recipes:

```
 powershell_script "Derp" do
  code <<-EOH
  new-service \
  -name derp "C:/path/myservice.exe" \
  -displayName "derp" \
  -StartupType Automatic \
  -Description "derp Service"
  EOH
```

So this runs fine on first run, but then it generates errors for subsequent runs because the service already exists.

Is the only solution here to do my own guarding? I like to avoid doing my own conditional in my recipes where ever possible. I can't be the only one with this problem, but I can't find a lot of examples online of how to solve this the chef way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you think Chef doesn't support creating services, the `:enable` action of the `service` resource works on Windows just like everywhere else.

Comment: What? Can you give me an example of how I can use :enable to create a new windows service which runs "C:/path/myservice.exe". I didn't think it could do that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, services generally register themselves and then Chef would set the startup params. Is `myservice.exe` a normal executable or an actual service? Windows services aren't like Linux where you can use any normal program.

Comment: You can see what I'm doing in that script, creating a new windows service that points to an exe- a NEW service that may or may not already exist.

Comment: But is the exe an actual service or not?

Comment: Basically we have some helpers like `Win32::Service.exists?(name)` that can be used for idempotence checks but it depends on the specifics.

Comment: But most Windows services either have a `/register` or register themselves automatically when run as a non-service.

Comment: not sure, don't think this exe has a /register switch, but even so I stilll would not be able to use the `service` provider with that right? Right now I"m using a guard with Win32::Service.exists?, but was wondering if the `service` provider can do this for me.

Comment: This sounds like it probably isn't an actual service executable.